# Yoxview JQuery Plugin IE9 Compatibility Situation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer-9

Ok so I've created an Image Gallery on a website and I use the Yoxview Plugin to create a slideshow / zoom feature to the Gallery. My problem comes from IE9 however. On Chrome the plugin works fine, I can play the slideshow and switch between images just fine. 
However, when I try clicking the next button in the Popup window on IE9, the image resizes, and becomes blank. It doesn't display the next image in the list.

I haven't changed any of the yoxview code and call it using the noscript shortcut, detailed on the website: http://www.yoxigen.com/yoxview/usage.aspx#installation

If anyone has any ideas why this could be happening, or how to fix, I'd appreciate any info you can give :)

Tried to find where the error may have been arising from in the jquery.yoxview-2.21.js file to no avail. my code is simply:

```
 <div class='yoxview' id='med_photos'>";



    $q = $db->query("SELECT * FROM photos WHERE album_id = '$aid'");

    while($ar = $q->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH))

    {

        $url = $ar['photo_url'];

        list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($url);

        if($width > $height)

        {

            $newWidth = 450;

            $newHeight = ($height/$width) * $newWidth;

        }

        else if($height > $width)

        {

            $newHeight = 300;

            $newWidth = ($width/$height) * $newHeight;
        }
        echo "<a href='" . $url ."'> <img src='".$url."' width='".$newWidth."' height='".$newHeight."' class='photo_holder' /></a> ";
    }
    echo "</div>
```

Comment: Posting some code might help. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added code to question